# how do not use a proxy configuration for the client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

to perform an ingestion of data retrieve from the internet and put them on a s3 bucket from an EC2
I need to use a proxy for the internet connection, but not for S3, and if I use my http_proxy and https_proxy variables,
the s3 client also uses the proxy.

is it possible when creating the S3 client, to tell him not to use the proxy ?

Answer (score 2):

Put S3 domain on `no_proxy` environment variable.

`export no_proxy=s3.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 1):

Configure proxies in the client to an empty dictionary.
https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config


config = Config(proxies={})
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', config=config)
```